# jquery issue with Agnosia Bootsrap Carousel in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the WordPress plugin Agnosia Bootstrap Carousel by AuSoft. However, the plugin can't properly create a carousel due to jQuery loading error : 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at the line :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) { $('#agnosia-bootstrap-carousel').carousel( { interval : 5000 , pause : "hover" } ); } );
```

I use chrome so I looked and jQuery exists but the parameter $ doesn't seems to work...

I try to load a new jQuery in wordpress I got the previous error.
And when I don't I have the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

If you want to take a look : [Error Here](http://poillic.com/?p=33)

What should I do to make this plugin works ?

Comment: seems it is not included correctly. have you checked the path again? post how you have included jquery

Comment: I have included jQuery this way 
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery2.js', false,'1.0',false); in functions.php